# How to convert a float variable to nvarchar(255)

Tags: sql-server

I have a field named `StudentID` in `TableA`. It's currently in `float` format. How do I make it `nvarchar(255)`?

Comment: Use the `str()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just query it AS nvarchar(255):

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(250), StudentID) FROM TableA
```

If you want to change the table structure:

```
ALTER TABLE TableA ALTER COLUMN StudentID NVARCHAR(255);
```

But why?

Comment: Thanks. Basically I upload an excel file to Sql server. However, this time one of the field type has changed, which cause the whole query to break. I feel like I have to change the field type in order to make the query run through.

Comment: If there is a few rows (records) with bad values, you need find them out and correct or remove them. Converting them to nvarchar(255) will cover all bad values.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! I just did a Filter in Excel and the values look correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`STR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx)

```
SELECT STR(@i,255)
```

Where `@i` is your float